# (SQL) I want a specific row output from the given table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Userid  some_other_id   phn_id   date1       date2        date3        date4
3       21              1322     09-DEC-15   31-DEC-99    01-JAN-00    31/12/9999
3       22              1322     09-DEC-15   31-DEC-99    01-JAN-00    31/12/9999
4       23              1322     21-AUG-15   25-AUG-06    01-OCT-03    31/12/9999
4       24              1322     21-AUG-15   31-DEC-99    25-AUG-06    31/12/9999 
5       22              1322     09-DEC-15   31-DEC-99    01-JAN-00    31/12/9999
5       22              1322     01-OCT-03   25-AUG-06    01-JAN-00    31/12/9999
6       23              1321     21-AUG-15   25-AUG-06    01-OCT-03    31/12/9999
6       24              1322     21-AUG-15   31-DEC-99    25-AUG-06    31/12/9999
```

What I want:

1. I want all userid/row where
2. some_user_id doesn't match for a same userid.
3. phn_id sould be 1322
4. After the above two conditions get satisfied I want to check whether any of the date columns are not matching to each other for a same userid.
   Result: In the example above I am expecting output for userId 4 as date2 and date3 are not matching.

Update: I have updated the sample data for further clarification.
I am still expecting the result userid 4 as rest all are not satisfying the conditions.
Explanation:-
Userid 3:dates are matching.(I want different dates for different some_other_id).
Userid 5: some_other_id is same.
Userid 6: phn_id is different.

Sorry, if I got you guys confused with the question. Let me know if any other details required.

Comment: To clarify you question, please post your table structure, some sample data according to the table structure, the needed result for that data, what you tried so far and the problems you are having with your code. Here you find something useful on [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I have already posted the table code snippet. Please run the code snippet and check the table structure and sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `not exists` clause and write your criteria there or some analytic function to count occurences and then filter them. Sample SQL with `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
  from t t1
  where userid <> some_other_id and phn_id = 1322
    and not exists (select 1 from t t2 
                     where t1.rowid <> t2.rowid and t1.userid = t2.userid 
                       and t1.date1 = t2.date1 and t1.date2 = t2.date2 
                       and t1.date3 = t2.date3 and t1.date4 = t2.date4 )
```

---

**Edit:** After your further clarifications the old query above does not work, my idea is:

```
select * 
  from (
    select t.*,
           count(1) over (partition by userid) cnt_phn,
           count(distinct some_other_id) over (partition by userid) cnt_id,
           count(1) over (partition by userid, date1, date2, date3, date4) cnt_dt
      from t where phn_id = 1322 )
  where cnt_phn > 1 and cnt_id > 1 and cnt_dt = 1
  order by userid, some_other_id
```

If you run only inner query you can see, for each user_id: `cnt_phn` number of phones with number 1322, `cnt_id` - number of distinct some_other_id for this user and `cnt_dt` - which counts dates for each tuple.
Outer query filters data according to your criteria. With your updated sample data it shows only user 4, as expected. This query may need adjustments if You find any issues, but here You have two ways how to achieve your goals: `exist` and analytic functions. Hope this helps.

Test data:

```
create table t (Userid number(3), some_other_id number(3), phn_id number(6), date1 date, date2 date, date3 date, date4 date);
insert into t values (3, 21, 1322, date '2015-12-09', date '1999-12-31', date '2000-01-01', date '9999-12-31');
insert into t values (3, 22, 1322, date '2015-12-09', date '1999-12-31', date '2000-01-01', date '9999-12-31');
insert into t values (4, 23, 1322, date '2015-08-21', date '2006-08-25', date '2003-10-01', date '9999-12-31');
insert into t values (4, 24, 1322, date '2015-08-21', date '1999-12-31', date '2006-08-25', date '9999-12-31');
insert into t values (5, 22, 1322, date '2015-12-09', date '1999-12-31', date '2000-01-01', date '9999-12-31');
insert into t values (5, 22, 1322, date '2003-10-01', date '2006-08-25', date '2000-01-01', date '9999-12-31');
insert into t values (6, 23, 1321, date '2015-08-21', date '2006-08-25', date '2003-10-01', date '9999-12-31');
insert into t values (6, 24, 1322, date '2015-08-21', date '2015-12-31', date '2006-08-25', date '9999-12-31');
```

Output:

```
USERID SOME_OTHER_ID  PHN_ID DATE1       DATE2       DATE3       DATE4
------ ------------- ------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
     4            23    1322 2015-08-21  2006-08-25  2003-10-01  9999-12-31
     4            23    1322 2015-08-21  1999-12-31  2006-08-25  9999-12-31
```

Comment: Hi, I do not want to compare userid with some_other_id as you are doing here "userid <> some_other_id". I rather want to take one userid and compare its some_other_id with each other. For an example: for the userid 4 first i want to check whether the some_other_id(i.e., 23,23 as you have taken) is matching or not. If not then only I want to check other conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your query helped a lot. :)

Comment: Just a little help needed. Can this query be optimized ?
As for me this query is taking around 11-12 mins to execute.